Per-pixel cosine similarity between features of two images
We are given two 3D matrices HxWxC where H,W are the dimensions of the 2D images and C the per-pixel features. We want to calculate the arg-maximum cosine similarity of each pixel feature of the first image with each pixel feature of the second image, or equivalently we need an HxW array that stores the pixel coordinates of the second image that has the maximum cosine similarity for every pixel in the first image.
For small enough H,W and C this can be easily and very efficiently computed with
torch.nn.CosineSimilarity() 
after vectorization where you can get an HxWxHxW matrix, and then compute the argmax for the last two rows.
If though, H and W are bigger (specifically let's say we have an 800x800 image) and the feature dimension C is 1500, the previous solution is not memory efficient. Even trying vectorizing per column and using only one for-loop requires more than enough memory.
So, the question is, is there an efficient way timewise and memorywise to compute the positions of the maximum per-pixel cosine similarity for two images in GPU?
Thank you!

IIUC you need something like nearest neighbour algorithm, fit for one image, tested for the other. For example Ball Tree or KD Tree,  with  cosine metric

Why I would suggest is first flatten your original image,resulting in a (800*800, 1500) vector v.
If this fits in memory, I would to the scalar product then argmax of a section of v with itself, consuming no additional memory than the chunk of v used (although it might even be a reference to v used in the scalar product so no more memory used). then you only store the argmax indices in a (800*800) shape vector.
v: torch.Tensor = ...
v = torch.flatten(v)

chunk_size: int = 50 # arbitrary chunk size

argmax_flat_indices = []
for cursor in range(0, len(v), chunk_size):
    # Here compute the cosine sim between v and v[cursor: cursor + chunk_size]
    # Do also the argmax along dim 1
    chunk_argmax_indices = ...

    argmax_flat_indices.append(chunk_argmax_indices)
    

argmax_flat_indices = torch.cat(argmax_flat_indices)

#Then compute back original indices
...

Would this fit you ?
